# How to define INT type parameters in airflow templating?

Tags: airflow

In my airflow task code, I'm able to declare and access string type parameters. However, when trying to assign INT type parameters, as follows,

```
task = Operator(
  task_id = 'task_name',
  parameters={"key1":"value1", "key2": 123}
)
```

I'm getting the following error

`Type '<type 'int'>' used for parameter 'parameters[key2]' is not supported for templating`
Are there ways to declare INT type parameters in airflow?

Comment: Please provide the actual process code and stacktrace.